# Legitimate and Credible SEO Sites and Seminars/Webinars

Tags: seo

In my opinion a lot of SEO information online tends to have a very "spammy" feel to it. Can anyone point me to some truly credible and legitimate SEO websites and/or seminars/webinars (other than stackexchange)? I'd like to learn more about SEO but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Since this is more of a collection of knowledge and there is no one right answer I have made it community wiki

Answer (score 3):

I write a column for SearchEngineWatch, and these are the resources I read:

For link building (my niche):

http://www.wiep.net
http://www.ericward.com/
http://www.linkspiel.com/
http://ontolo.com/blog
http://www.canadianseo.com/
http://www.buzzstream.com/blog/
http://www.wordtracker.com/blog
http://www.stuntdubl.com/

For general SEO:

http://www.seoroundtable.com
http://www.distilled.co.uk/blog/
http://www.measuredsem.com/blog
http://www.blueglass.com/blog/
http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/
http://www.wolf-howl.com
http://www.outspokenmedia.com
http://www.verticalmeasures.com/blog/
http://blog.zetainteractive.com/
http://www.hugoguzman.com/
http://www.seo-theory.com
http://www.higherrankings.com
http://www.oilman.ca/ (wish he had more time to blog)

For general search marketing news/potpourri:
http://www.searchenginewatch.com
http://www.searchengineland.com
http://www.searchenginejournal.com

Forums

http://www.webmasterworld.com
http://community.seobook.com/forum.php

Conferences:
SMX West http://searchmarketingexpo.com/west/
SMX Advanced http://searchmarketingexpo.com/advanced/
Pubcon http://www.pubcon.com/
Distilled Link Building Seminar  https://www.distilled.co.uk/events/linkbuilding-seminar-2011

Answer (score 2):

SEOMoz [seomoz.org](http://seomoz.org)

has some great information and tools. There's a wide variety of articles and good advice.